# Interpreting package requests conflicts for a failed conda install

Tags: python, conda, hadoop-yarn, dask, rapids

Attempting the following `conda install` operation (derived from the [NVIDIA RAPIDS installation instructions](https://rapids.ai/start.html)):

```
conda config --prepend channels rapidsai && \
conda config --prepend channels nvidia && \
conda config --set channel_priority strict && \
conda install \
-c conda-forge \
-y \
-q \
dask-yarn>=0.7.0 \
pyarrow \
s3fs \
conda-pack \
tornado=5 \
python=3.7 \
bokeh \
fastparquet \
python-snappy \
snappy \
rapids=0.14
```

On an AWS EC2 instance (specifically, an `m5.xlarge`) this failed, with the following (comically long; I've provided a snippet here, [click here for a gist with the full version](https://gist.github.com/ResidentMario/732fd0545a7808aaf8e7e322fb1e1895)) output explaining package conflicts:

```
Determining conflicts:   0%|          | 0/47 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn rapids:   0%|          | 0/47 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:   2%|▏         | 1/47 [00:00<00:44,  1.04it/s]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:   4%|▍         | 2/47 [00:00<00:21,  2.09it/s]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python sqlite brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids readline conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:   4%|▍         | 2/47 [00:11<00:21,  2.09it/s]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python sqlite brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids readline conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:   6%|▋         | 3/47 [00:11<02:37,  3.58s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn rapids bokeh:   6%|▋         | 3/47 [00:22<02:37,  3.58s/it]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Examining conflict for dask-yarn rapids bokeh:   9%|▊         | 4/47 [00:22<04:09,  5.80s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi ncurses wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser libedit tornado pycosat snappy ruamel_yaml pip yaml python sqlite brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet libstdcxx-ng cryptography rapids readline conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools libffi six conda:   9%|▊         | 4/47 [00:22<04:09,  5.80s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cryptography urllib3 pyopenssl brotlipy conda fastparquet:  11%|█         | 5/47 [00:33<04:03,  5.80s/it]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cryptography urllib3 pyopenssl brotlipy conda fastparquet:  13%|█▎        | 6/47 [00:33<03:54,  5.71s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn s3fs rapids:  13%|█▎        | 6/47 [00:35<03:54,  5.71s/it]                                              
Examining conflict for dask-yarn s3fs rapids:  15%|█▍        | 7/47 [00:35<03:05,  4.64s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks openssl s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  15%|█▍        | 7/47 [00:37<03:05,  4.64s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks openssl s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  17%|█▋        | 8/47 [00:37<02:30,  3.86s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip brotlipy pyarrow tqdm fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  17%|█▋        | 8/47 [00:48<02:30,  3.86s/it]               
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip brotlipy pyarrow tqdm fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  19%|█▉        | 9/47 [00:48<03:48,  6.00s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python sqlite brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  19%|█▉        | 9/47 [01:00<03:48,  6.00s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python sqlite brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  21%|██▏       | 10/47 [01:00<04:43,  7.66s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat xz ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  21%|██▏       | 10/47 [01:11<04:43,  7.66s/it]    
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat xz ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  23%|██▎       | 11/47 [01:11<05:12,  8.69s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi ncurses wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser libedit tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python sqlite brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids readline conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  23%|██▎       | 11/47 [01:22<05:12,  8.69s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi ncurses wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser libedit tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python sqlite brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids readline conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  26%|██▌       | 12/47 [01:22<05:28,  9.37s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn bokeh tornado:  26%|██▌       | 12/47 [01:33<05:28,  9.37s/it]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Examining conflict for dask-yarn bokeh tornado:  28%|██▊       | 13/47 [01:33<05:34,  9.85s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna ld_impl_linux-64 requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  28%|██▊       | 13/47 [01:34<05:34,  9.85s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna ld_impl_linux-64 requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  30%|██▉       | 14/47 [01:34<04:00,  7.28s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi tk wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet zlib idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python sqlite brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  30%|██▉       | 14/47 [01:45<04:00,  7.28s/it]  
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi tk wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet zlib idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python sqlite brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  32%|███▏      | 15/47 [01:45<04:27,  8.37s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn bokeh:  32%|███▏      | 15/47 [01:56<04:27,  8.37s/it]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Examining conflict for dask-yarn bokeh:  34%|███▍      | 16/47 [01:56<04:43,  9.16s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn pyarrow:  34%|███▍      | 16/47 [01:56<04:43,  9.16s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn pyarrow:  36%|███▌      | 17/47 [01:56<03:14,  6.50s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi tk wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  36%|███▌      | 17/47 [02:01<03:14,  6.50s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi tk wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  38%|███▊      | 18/47 [02:01<02:50,  5.87s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn bokeh tornado fastparquet:  38%|███▊      | 18/47 [02:12<02:50,  5.87s/it]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Examining conflict for dask-yarn bokeh tornado fastparquet:  40%|████      | 19/47 [02:12<03:27,  7.41s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn six cryptography rapids conda-package-handling urllib3 tornado pyopenssl bokeh pyarrow conda fastparquet:  40%|████      | 19/47 [02:15<03:27,  7.41s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn six cryptography rapids conda-package-handling urllib3 tornado pyopenssl bokeh pyarrow conda fastparquet:  43%|████▎     | 20/47 [02:15<02:45,  6.12s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cryptography requests urllib3 pyopenssl conda:  43%|████▎     | 20/47 [02:19<02:45,  6.12s/it]                                                           
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cryptography requests urllib3 pyopenssl conda:  45%|████▍     | 21/47 [02:19<02:18,  5.34s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn rapids bokeh pyarrow fastparquet:  45%|████▍     | 21/47 [02:19<02:18,  5.34s/it]             
Examining conflict for dask-yarn rapids bokeh pyarrow fastparquet:  47%|████▋     | 22/47 [02:19<01:37,  3.89s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi tk ncurses wheel urllib3 pysocks openssl libgcc-ng s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet zlib idna requests pycparser libedit tornado pycosat xz ruamel_yaml snappy pip yaml python sqlite brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids readline conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools libffi six conda:  47%|████▋     | 22/47 [02:21<01:37,  3.89s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi tk ncurses wheel urllib3 pysocks openssl libgcc-ng s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet zlib idna requests pycparser libedit tornado pycosat xz ruamel_yaml snappy pip yaml python sqlite brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids readline conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools libffi six conda:  49%|████▉     | 23/47 [02:21<01:21,  3.39s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools libffi six conda:  49%|████▉     | 23/47 [02:33<01:21,  3.39s/it]                                                                         
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks s3fs bokeh python-snappy certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography rapids conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools libffi six conda:  51%|█████     | 24/47 [02:33<02:12,  5.76s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn conda-package-handling tornado bokeh pyarrow conda:  51%|█████     | 24/47 [02:43<02:12,  5.76s/it]                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Examining conflict for dask-yarn conda-package-handling tornado bokeh pyarrow conda:  53%|█████▎    | 25/47 [02:43<02:40,  7.31s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks openssl s3fs bokeh python-snappy ca-certificates certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  53%|█████▎    | 25/47 [02:45<02:40,  7.31s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn cffi wheel urllib3 pysocks openssl s3fs bokeh python-snappy ca-certificates certifi chardet idna requests pycparser tornado pycosat ruamel_yaml pip python brotlipy tqdm pyarrow fastparquet cryptography conda-package-handling conda-pack pyopenssl setuptools six conda:  55%|█████▌    | 26/47 [02:45<01:57,  5.61s/it]
Examining conflict for dask-yarn python rapids fastparquet wheel conda-pack setuptools bokeh pyarrow ruamel_yaml conda pip:  55%|█████▌    | 26/47 [02:56<01:57,  5.61s/it]                                                                                                                                                                                 
Examining conflict for dask-yarn python rapids fastparquet wheel conda-pack setuptools bokeh pyarrow ruamel_yaml conda pip:  57%|█████▋    | 27/47 [02:56<02:23,  7.18s/it]
Examining conflict for tk ncurses openssl libgcc-ng python-snappy zlib libedit tornado pycosat xz ruamel_yaml snappy yaml python sqlite brotlipy pyarrow fastparquet _libgcc_mutex cryptography readline conda-package-handling libffi cffi:  57%|█████▋    | 27/47 [02:59<02:23,  7.18s/it]
Examining conflict for tk ncurses openssl libgcc-ng python-snappy zlib libedit tornado pycosat xz ruamel_yaml snappy yaml python sqlite brotlipy pyarrow fastparquet _libgcc_mutex cryptography readline conda-package-handling libffi cffi:  60%|█████▉    | 28/47 [02:59<01:52,  5.92s/it]
Examining conflict for tk ncurses openssl libgcc-ng python-snappy zlib libedit tornado pycosat xz ruamel_yaml snappy yaml python sqlite brotlipy pyarrow fastparquet cryptography readline conda-package-handling libffi cffi:  60%|█████▉    | 28/47 [03:05<01:52,  5.92s/it]              
Examining conflict for tk ncurses openssl libgcc-ng python-snappy zlib libedit tornado pycosat xz ruamel_yaml snappy yaml python sqlite brotlipy pyarrow fastparquet cryptography readline conda-package-handling libffi cffi:  62%|██████▏   | 29/47 [03:05<01:49,  6.08s/it]
Examining conflict for wheel python pip:  62%|██████▏   | 29/47 [03:12<01:49,  6.08s/it]                                                                                                                                                                                      
Examining conflict for wheel python pip:  64%|██████▍   | 30/47 [03:12<01:45,  6.18s/it]
Examining conflict for requests pip wheel conda-pack urllib3 setuptools bokeh pyarrow ruamel_yaml conda certifi:  64%|██████▍   | 30/47 [03:12<01:45,  6.18s/it]
Examining conflict for urllib3 bokeh requests conda:  66%|██████▌   | 31/47 [03:18<01:38,  6.18s/it]                                                            
Examining conflict for urllib3 bokeh requests conda:  68%|██████▊   | 32/47 [03:18<01:18,  5.24s/it]
Examining conflict for urllib3 requests conda pyopenssl:  68%|██████▊   | 32/47 [03:19<01:18,  5.24s/it]
Examining conflict for urllib3 requests conda pyopenssl:  70%|███████   | 33/47 [03:19<00:57,  4.11s/it]
Examining conflict for cryptography urllib3 pyopenssl:  70%|███████   | 33/47 [03:20<00:57,  4.11s/it]  
Examining conflict for cryptography urllib3 pyopenssl:  72%|███████▏  | 34/47 [03:20<00:37,  2.92s/it]
Examining conflict for urllib3 requests pysocks:  72%|███████▏  | 34/47 [03:20<00:37,  2.92s/it]      
Examining conflict for urllib3 requests pysocks:  74%|███████▍  | 35/47 [03:20<00:26,  2.17s/it]
Examining conflict for idna requests cryptography urllib3 pyopenssl bokeh conda:  74%|███████▍  | 35/47 [03:20<00:26,  2.17s/it]
Examining conflict for idna requests cryptography urllib3 pyopenssl bokeh conda:  77%|███████▋  | 36/47 [03:20<00:17,  1.56s/it]
Examining conflict for cryptography urllib3 requests pyopenssl:  77%|███████▋  | 36/47 [03:22<00:17,  1.56s/it]                 
Examining conflict for cryptography urllib3 requests pyopenssl:  79%|███████▊  | 37/47 [03:22<00:16,  1.67s/it]
Examining conflict for cryptography urllib3 pyopenssl brotlipy cffi:  79%|███████▊  | 37/47 [03:22<00:16,  1.67s/it]
Examining conflict for cryptography urllib3 pyopenssl brotlipy cffi:  81%|████████  | 38/47 [03:22<00:11,  1.25s/it]
Examining conflict for brotlipy urllib3 requests:  81%|████████  | 38/47 [03:23<00:11,  1.25s/it]                   
Examining conflict for brotlipy urllib3 requests:  83%|████████▎ | 39/47 [03:23<00:08,  1.01s/it]
Examining conflict for rapids bokeh pyarrow fastparquet:  83%|████████▎ | 39/47 [03:23<00:08,  1.01s/it]
Examining conflict for rapids bokeh pyarrow fastparquet:  85%|████████▌ | 40/47 [03:23<00:05,  1.34it/s]
Examining conflict for bokeh yaml ruamel_yaml conda:  85%|████████▌ | 40/47 [03:31<00:05,  1.34it/s]    
Examining conflict for bokeh yaml ruamel_yaml conda:  87%|████████▋ | 41/47 [03:31<00:18,  3.02s/it]
Examining conflict for bokeh pyarrow:  87%|████████▋ | 41/47 [03:33<00:18,  3.02s/it]               
Examining conflict for bokeh pyarrow:  89%|████████▉ | 42/47 [03:33<00:12,  2.55s/it]
Examining conflict for bokeh pyarrow fastparquet:  89%|████████▉ | 42/47 [03:38<00:12,  2.55s/it]
Examining conflict for bokeh pyarrow fastparquet:  91%|█████████▏| 43/47 [03:38<00:13,  3.41s/it]
Examining conflict for cffi cryptography tornado setuptools brotlipy bokeh conda certifi:  91%|█████████▏| 43/47 [03:49<00:13,  3.41s/it]
Examining conflict for cffi cryptography tornado setuptools brotlipy bokeh conda certifi:  94%|█████████▎| 44/47 [03:49<00:16,  5.61s/it]
Examining conflict for bokeh fastparquet:  94%|█████████▎| 44/47 [03:51<00:16,  5.61s/it]                                                
Examining conflict for bokeh fastparquet:  96%|█████████▌| 45/47 [03:51<00:09,  4.51s/it]
Examining conflict for cffi cryptography conda-package-handling tornado setuptools brotlipy bokeh conda certifi:  96%|█████████▌| 45/47 [03:55<00:09,  4.51s/it]
Examining conflict for cffi cryptography conda-package-handling tornado setuptools brotlipy bokeh conda certifi:  98%|█████████▊| 46/47 [03:55<00:04,  4.34s/it]
Examining conflict for requests bokeh conda:  98%|█████████▊| 46/47 [03:57<00:04,  4.34s/it]                                                                    
Examining conflict for requests bokeh conda: 100%|██████████| 47/47 [03:57<00:00,  3.64s/it]
Examining conflict for chardet bokeh requests conda: 100%|██████████| 47/47 [03:57<00:00,  3.64s/it]
Examining conflict for bokeh tornado: : 48it [03:58,  3.64s/it]                                     
Examining conflict for bokeh tornado: : 49it [03:58,  2.78s/it]
Examining conflict for pyarrow snappy python-snappy: : 49it [03:59,  2.78s/it]
Examining conflict for pyarrow snappy python-snappy: : 50it [03:59,  2.33s/it]
Examining conflict for pycparser brotlipy cryptography cffi: : 50it [04:04,  2.33s/it]
Examining conflict for pycparser brotlipy cryptography cffi: : 51it [04:04,  2.89s/it]
Examining conflict for python libedit sqlite: : 51it [04:04,  2.89s/it]               
Examining conflict for python libedit sqlite: : 52it [04:04,  2.09s/it]
Examining conflict for conda pycosat: : 52it [04:04,  2.09s/it]        
Examining conflict for ruamel_yaml conda: : 53it [04:04,  2.09s/it]
Examining conflict for conda tqdm conda-package-handling: : 54it [04:04,  2.09s/it]
Examining conflict for rapids pyarrow: : 55it [04:04,  2.09s/it]                   
Examining conflict for rapids pyarrow: : 56it [04:04,  1.47s/it]
Examining conflict for pyarrow conda-package-handling: : 56it [04:04,  1.47s/it]
Examining conflict for rapids fastparquet: : 57it [04:12,  1.47s/it]            
Examining conflict for rapids fastparquet: : 58it [04:12,  2.29s/it]
Examining conflict for conda conda-package-handling: : 58it [04:14,  2.29s/it]
Examining conflict for conda conda-package-handling: : 59it [04:14,  2.15s/it]
                                                                              
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package ncurses conflicts for:
ncurses
sqlite -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='6.0.*|>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0']
fastparquet -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
pysocks -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
pip -> python[version='>=3'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
tqdm -> python -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
conda-package-handling -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9|5.9.*|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0']
urllib3 -> python[version='<4.0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
pyopenssl -> python -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
bokeh -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
python-snappy -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
pycosat -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
rapids=0.14 -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
wheel -> python -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
tornado=5 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9|5.9.*|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0']
requests -> python -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
pyarrow -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
sqlite -> ncurses[version='5.9|5.9.*|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0']
python=3.7 -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0']
certifi -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
conda[version='>=4.8.3'] -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
libedit -> ncurses[version='5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
readline -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
pycparser -> python -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
chardet -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
setuptools -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
cryptography -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
python=3.7 -> readline[version='>=8.0,<9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
s3fs -> python[version='>=3.5'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
six -> python -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
idna -> python -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
cffi -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
brotlipy -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.1'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
ruamel_yaml -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']
conda-pack -> python -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|5.9|>=6.1,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<6.3.0a0|>=6.2,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0|>=6.0,<7.0a0|6.0.*']

[...]

Package python_abi conflicts for:
dask-yarn -> grpcio[version='>=1.14.0'] -> python_abi[version='2.7.*|3.6',build='*_cp27mu|*_pypy36_pp73']
dask-yarn -> python_abi[version='3.6.*|3.8.*|3.7.*',build='*_cp36m|*_cp38|*_cp37m']

Package numba conflicts for:
rapids=0.14 -> cudf=0.14 -> numba[version='>=0.40.1|>=0.49.0|>=0.49']
rapids=0.14 -> numba[version='>=0.49,<0.50a']

Package pycosat conflicts for:
pycosat
conda[version='>=4.8.3'] -> pycosat[version='>=0.6.3']
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

I do not know how to interpret this output. Take the following list of purported package conflicts for `numba`, for example:

```
Package numba conflicts for:
rapids=0.14 -> cudf=0.14 -> numba[version='>=0.40.1|>=0.49.0|>=0.49']
rapids=0.14 -> numba[version='>=0.49,<0.50a']
```

This seems easily satisfiable: just install `numba==0.49`. The logs seem to be populated with such resolvable irresolvable conflicts.

Does anyone know why `conda` is providing such output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just running :

```
conda install \
-c conda-forge \
-y \
-q \
dask-yarn>=0.7.0 \
pyarrow \
s3fs \
conda-pack \
tornado=5 \
python=3.7 \
bokeh \
fastparquet \
python-snappy \
snappy \
rapids=0.14 cudatoolkit=10.2
```

without updating `conda config` works for me in my system. All the required libraries are installed without any issues or errors. Why are you updating `conda config`?

Comment: This shouldn't work, actually. Can you double check the `rapids` package to see if you are getting the right one? There is a [conda-forge rapids package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/rapids) which is totally unrelated to the NVIDIA `rapids` package.

Comment: You are trying to install the rapids package which contains cudf, cuml and the other rapidsai libraries mentioned in https://rapids.ai/start.html, right?
I am able to import these libraries using ipython
Also once I ran the conda config commands you have provided above I had to reset my conda config to its default configuration before running the conda install command.

Answer (score 2):

even if you get this working, this will fail to install RAPIDS is because an m5 instance doesn't have a GPU.  You need a p3 or g4 instance for AWS.